# How to configure routes in createBrowserRouter function in react-rotuer-dom with arrow function components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am creating a simple react app with `react-router-dom` for routing. When I am exporting the default component as `Component`, it works fine with the lazy option in the `createBrowserRouter` function, but when it is a simple arrow function component, I am getting the error `Matched leaf route at location "/about" does not have an element or Component`.

So my `App.jsx` looks like:

```
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "./Layout";
import "./styles.css";

const routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "about",
        lazy: () => import("./pages/About")
      },
      {
        path: "contact",
        lazy: () => import("./pages/Contact")
      }
    ]
  }
]);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <RouterProvider router={routes} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

pages/contact.jsx

```
export function Component() {
  return <h1> Contact </h1>;
}

export default Component;
```

pages/about.jsx

```
export const About = () => {
  return <h1> About </h1>;
};

export default About;
```

The contact page is rendered as expected, but the `About` page is not rendered when I use the `lazy` option. What am I doing wrong?

For a quick preview: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-nightingale-956xxv?file=/src/pages/About.jsx

Comment: FWIW I don't see the `"/contact"` route in your sandbox working either.

Comment: @DrewReese can you check the pages folder?

Comment: The "/src/pages" directory in the repo/sandbox? What about it?

Comment: It contains both About.tsx and Contact.tsx. When we are doing like export function Component() {
  return <h1> Contact </h1>;
}

export default Component;
It is working and when we are doing like export const About = () => {
  return <h1> About </h1>;
};

export default About;
 it is not working

Comment: I think you misunderstood my initial comment. In your sandbox neither implementation is working. Neither route/page component loads or mounts from what I saw.

Comment: @DrewReese That is what i am telling. What am I doing wrong? This is happening only when i use the lazy option

Answer (score 0):

The component being lazily imported should be named `Component`, or rather, whatever component is being exported should be named `Component`. It doesn't matter if the React component is a Class component or a `function` or arrow function component.

The following works:

About.jsx

```
export const Component = () => {
  return <h1>About</h1>;
};
```

Contact.jsx

```
export function Component() {
  return <h1>Contact</h1>;
}
```

App.jsx

```
const routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "about",
        lazy: () => import("./pages/About")
      },
      {
        path: "contact",
        lazy: () => import("./pages/Contact")
      },
      {
        path: "*",
        element: <h1>No Match</h1>
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

If you prefer to use a different named export, or the file exports several components then you can destructure the appropriate named export and return an object with a `Component` property.

Example:

About.jsx

```
export const About = () => {
  return <h1>About</h1>;
};
```

App.jsx

```
const routes = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "about",
        lazy: async () => {
          const { About } = await import("./pages/About");
          return { Component: About };
        }
      },
      {
        path: "contact",
        lazy: () => import("./pages/Contact")
      },
      {
        path: "*",
        element: <h1>No Match</h1>
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Can you explain why it is like this? I am wondering because I was not able to find this in documentation or I was not aware of the same

Comment: @JimParsons I don't think I can provide any more an explanation other than what I already provided. I basically figured it out from the example code in the documentation and the official [example demo](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/dev/examples/lazy-loading-router-provider) and put two and two together. They don't explicitly call this out. The RRDv6 docs are notoriously incomplete in some areas, or newer features just haven't been documented well enough or not at all. The RRD maintainers generally welcome PRs to improve the documentation.